# Why isn't my coffee script function defined when I visit my page via a "link_to" link?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, function, coffeescript, onload

I’m using **Rails 4.2.7**.  On a particular page (/users/edit), I have this link

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", {:controller => :my_objects, :action => 'index' }, :class => 'btn' %>
```

when I click on the link, I’m whisked away to the right page, in which I have a coffee script that is supposed to be executed.  It contains this

```
$ ->
  #("#add_form).click ->
    console.log(" invoking function load. ")
    setup_save_behavior()
…
setup_save_behavior = () ->
  $("a.modal_button").unbind('click')
  $("a.modal_button").click ->
    # Setup action
    $('#new_my_object').attr('action', '/my_objects/create')
    $('#_method').val('')
    # Clear existing error messages
    clear_form_errors()
    # Clear existing form elements
    $(':input[name^=my_object]','#new_my_object')
      .not(':button, :submit, :reset')
      .val('')
      .removeAttr('checked')
      .removeAttr('selected');
```

What is strange is that when I click on my link above, I get the JS error on the page

```
my_objects.self-50d1edb….js?body=1:16 Uncaught TypeError: setup_save_behavior is not a function
```

even though the console.log is executed (I can see " invoking function load. " printed out).  If I actually go into my URL’s address bar and then type my URL, “http://loclahost:3000/my_objects/index,” then everything loads fine and there are no Javascript errors.  I’m totally baffled.  What can I do so that my function gets defined when I click on the link defined by the “link_to” script?

Comment: try creating a jsfiddle to reproduce the error, that way would be easier to help.

Comment: Try nuking turbolinks by appending `, data: {no_turbolink: true}` on the end of your `link_to`. When you use the address bar to navigate, you're forcing a full load and you're getting a load event properly. Turbolinks sometimes gets stupid and tries to save you overhead by caching resources, which has the effect of stepping on load events.

Comment: I changed my link to "<%= link_to "Cancel", {:controller => :races, :action => 'index' }, :class => 'btn', data: {no_turbolink: true} %>" but alsa the function still isn't defined when I visit my page by clicking on the generated link.

Comment: I removed "//= require turoblinks" from my app/assets/javascript/application.js file and now everything works just fine.  Stupid turbolinks.  What is the point of it if it causes nothing to work normally in your site?

Comment: Just learned something new. See answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks can cause problems in your Rails app because it tries to save overhead by maintaining assets listed in the `<head>` element of your page (among other things). When you load a page using a full load (via refresh button), an actual `ready` event takes place and your scripts work. On the other hand, if you were to visit a page some other way (via link), Turbolinks tries to reuse the `<head>` element, so there's no `ready` event fired.

The solution in the past was to simply disable Turbolinks, either entirely, by removing its `require` line in `application.js` or by link (`data: {no_turbolink: true}`). With Rails 4.2.x and 5.x, you can listen for a Turbolinks related event that should work where a normal `ready` event would have worked before.

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks):

> However, because Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process,
>   the event that this relies on will not be fired. If you have code that
>   looks like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

> you must change your code to do this instead:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

(quote rearranged slightly for clarity)